# Optimizing Box2D for a couple hundred static bodies

Tags: c++, box2d

I searched but could not find anything similar (Yet) around the web, so here I am asking my question:
In my game I use around 3 to 4 hundred static bodies with like 10 dynamic bodies in the Box2D world. The problem is that after 100 static bodies it cant manage 60 frames / second. My understanding is that static bodies calculate faster then dynamic ones.
My rendering is pretty much bound to the iterator, so optimizing the game through removing objects entirelly is not really an option.
Is there a way I can speed up the physics sim for static bodies? I think about something like statics far from dynamics would be just jumped in the world step...
So generally I want to speed up the sim of static bodies, or completely not simulate them without removing them from the BodyIterator.
I am open to any suggestions.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you show us some context for how these static bodies are placed? A common use case where this could come up for example would be creating colliders for individual tiles in a tile map, instead of merging them together into a smaller number of static obstacles.

Comment: The static bodies are boxes wich form the kind-of circular shape, yes they constantly collide with each other, but setting custom collision groups, so they ignore eachother does not help... I cant really use a tile map, these boxes are teeny tiny and i need like a couple thousand of them. I havent tried putting them to "sleep" yet, what does that do exactly?

Comment: If they're static bodies they shouldn't process collisions with one another at all. Can you show us a picture? It sounds very much like there could be a more efficient solution to your problem, but first we need to clearly understand what problem you're using these static bodies to solve.